# How to get "Test Results.csv" from "Test Results Analyzer Plugin" in jenkins？

Tags: python, jenkins, junit, plugins

hi，I want to get "Test Results.csv" from "Test Results Analyzer Plugin" in jenkins. 
What I started thinking about was download it by request lib in python. However, it's a dynamic link as below, not static like picture url link. So maybe I can simulate a mouse click to download it by Selenium with Python But it's not optimal. Or is there a direct interface to access the accumulated data in "Test Results.csv".
Is there any smart way to do this? Thanks

```
jQuery("#downloadCSV").click(function () {
    var noOfBuilds = "-1";

    if (!jQuery("#allnoofbuilds").is(":checked")) {
        noOfBuilds = jQuery("#noofbuilds").val();
    }
    remoteAction.getExportCSV(displayValues, noOfBuilds, function(t) {
        download("Test Results.csv", t.responseObject());
    })
});
```